# Chrome Browser Extension - Retrieve JSON from injected script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I am developing a browser extension for Chrome that uses a content script in order to insert JavaScript into webpages, so that I can then get RUM data that I can use to analyze page load times. While I have already generated the data I want from the page, I have found myself unable to send the data to a server, as I get error messages stating that I have violated the Content Security Policy of the page that I am attempting to retrieve data about (currently just trying to send via a XHR).

Does anyone know how I can successfully send the data to a server after I have collected it?

Comment: Did you add [permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) for the server url?

Comment: Yeah, I have the permissions set to http://*/* and https://*/*

Comment: You will have to include more info such as your manifest and how you are making the request.